# Hashing, can't insert to hash table

Tags: hashtable

```
struct googlePlayApp{
    string name;
    string category;
    double rating;
    int reviews;
    googlePlayApp *next;
};
```

```
  void appInsert(googlePlayApp &newApp, int &cmps) {
    int slot = hash1(newApp.name, HASH_SIZE);
    int cmps1 = 1;
    googlePlayApp *tmp = appHash[slot];

    if (tmp == 0)
        appHash[slot] = &newApp;
    else
    {
        while(tmp->next != 0)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            cmps1++;
        }
        tmp->next = &newApp;
    }
    cmps += cmps1;
}
```

```
    while (getline(inFile, inputLine)) {
        googlePlayApp newApp;
        readSingleApp(inputLine, newApp);
        appInsert(newApp, cmps);
        linesRead++;
    }
```

My program stops on the 65th iteration of the while loop....
64th for the appInsert call...
Why can't I get this to work?
This is a program where it reads a data file and stores it in a hash table and collision dealt with open addressing....

**updated question**

```
bool appFind(const string &name, googlePlayApp &foundApp, int &cmps) {
    // Implement this function
    int slot = hash1(name);
    int cmps1 = 1;
    googlePlayApp *tmp = appHash[slot];

    while(tmp && tmp->name != name)
    {
        cmps1++;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    cmps += cmps1;

    if(tmp)
    {
        foundApp.name = appHash[slot]->name;
        foundApp.category = appHash[slot]->category;
        foundApp.rating = appHash[slot]->rating;
        foundApp.reviews = appHash[slot]->reviews;
    }
    else    return false;
}
```

this is my serach function and I'm trying to search if an app exists based on the data I stored from my code above. I'm trying to search it by the hash addresses, but it's not working...

Comment: is newapp->next initialized to 0 ?

Comment: no, does it have to be?

Comment: Yes. ```next == 0``` indicates the end of a chain to the loop in ```appInsert```.  When you add a new item to the end of the chain, it had better have 0 in ```next```` otherwise the result of the next call will be unpredictable.

Comment: oh I think I got it to work, I initialized my next to 0 in my struct. THanks!

Comment: But my search doesn't work...

Comment: Time to debug the algorithm, I'd say.  Print out in appFind the name you're looking for and the name of every entry you examine.  FWIW, the hash functions you used in appInsert and appFind are different (two args versus one arg),  And you're missing a 'return true' for the case you find the entry you want.